# NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Tags: python, global

I am trying to get value of global variable 'count' by calling function 'increase' but it's giving an error - 'NameError: name 'count' is not defined'. What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
class sampleclass: 
  count = 0  # class attribute 

  def increase(self):
    global count 
    count += 1

# Calling increase() on an object 
s1 = sampleclass() 
s1.increase()        
print(s1.count)
```

Comment: No need for `global`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class sampleclass: 
  count = 0  # class attribute 

  def increase(self):
    self.count += 1

# Calling increase() on an object 
s1 = sampleclass() 
s1.increase()        
print(s1.count)
```

You can't access `count` with `global`. You've got to use `self`. *Or*, if you want to be explicit, then do this:

```
class sampleclass: 
  count = 0  # class attribute 

  def increase(self):
    sampleclass.count += 1

# Calling increase() on an object 
s1 = sampleclass() 
s1.increase()        
print(s1.count)
```

You can do this because `count` is a class variable. You can also access `count` from outside the class like that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I would like to understand why does global not work here

Comment: @Giffen -- global does not work there because It is a class attribute. If you had multiple classes with the same class attributes, global would be a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it's a class attribute in the comments in your code.

```
class sampleclass: 
  count = 0  # class attribute 

  def increase(self):
      sampleclass.count += 1

# Calling increase() on an object 
s1 = sampleclass() 
s1.increase()        
print(s1.count)
```

I would recommend to make it as an object attribute